# Module build failed with syntax error at `(props: RenderNextPage = () => )

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-pdf-viewer

I am working with react pdf viewer package and webpack. When running the build i get a module builded failed with syntax error at `(props: RenderNextPage = () => ).` The problem is that props: is not allowing to build.

I have added @babel/preset-env and @babel/react-preset to .babelrc presets
The Webpack.config file looks like this

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    devServer: {
        static: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 8001,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html',
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
            ignoreOrder: false,
        }),
    ],
};
```

Comment: `(props: RenderNextPage = () => )` is not a valid javascript nor typescript

Comment: @Konrad actually i wrote it wrong. Heres a snippet of the code causing the error using jsx and the props

{(props: RenderGoToPageProps) => ()

where  props: fail to build

Comment: What is this `()` at the end?

Comment: @Konrad thanks for replying at least. I solved it already.  I didn't config the webpack properly for tsx and the tsconfig also. Switched module to common js targetted es5. Bundling Properly